# Binding issue with nested component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component A, inside I have component B.
Component A has a template displaying a binded property.

I click on component B button, which emit a message for component A.
Component A catch it and update the property but the template doesn't refresh the value.

If I click another time here I have the message displayed.

So for some reason its not refreshing the template with the message the first time, but why ?

I checked the logs and its hitting the onNotify properly.

Component A

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class ComponentA {

    message: string;

    constructor(...) {...}

    onNotify(message: string): void {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Component A Template

```
<div class="message">
  {{message}}
</div>
<component-b (notify)='onNotify($event)'></component-b>
```

Component B

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-b',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class ComponentB {

    @Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(...) {...}

    onClick() {
        this.notify.emit('Message');
    }
}
```

Here some of the deps I use

```
"@angular/common": "2.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
"@angular/core": "2.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.3.0",
"@angular/http": "2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.3.0",
"@angular/router": "3.3.0",
```

Thanks for your help to understand this.

Comment: It looks like you removed some of the redundant code from your post but it would be easier to help if we could see all the code. For example, do you have a changeDetection specified for your component in the full code? If so, what value do you have in there?

Comment: Thats basically the code I use. I dont have any specific changeDetection.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I'm not happy with it so if someone find a clean fix...

I forced the framework to detect the changes in my onNotify method.

I imported `ChangeDetectorRef` from `@angular/core`.
And used `detectChanges()` method, after my property update.

Answer (score 0):

ChangeDetectorRef is what you should use for this:

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class ComponentA {
      message: string;

      constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

      onNotify(message: string): void {
        this.message = message;
        // trigger the view update
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      }
}
```

Comment: Its not working, I still have to click twice to make the message appear.
With detectChanges() instead of markForCheck() its working though.